# Recursivly make .O files with g++?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++

I have my main.cpp file, and in that folder is another folder called src, and in that folder are more folders etc... How could I compile this easily with g++? I do not want to make a make file at this time because I'm still working on my project but I want to test in in Linux and OSX.

Thanks

Comment: FOR THE LOVE OF GOD MAN USE MAKEFILES!

Comment: "I do not want to use the accepted, perfectly reasonable, and easy way to do this at this time because I'm still working on my project." It makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it the right way, with a Makefile, or by making a list every time you build, something like:

```
g++ -Wall -o myapp `find . -name \*.cpp`
```

Comment: +1 because it actually tells him what hes looking for, but its drastically inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

`g++` doesn't manage your build process. It follows the unix philosophy of doing one thing and doing it well. This doesn't include build management.

Make a Makefile. Its what they are made for.